# flask-socketio server send without receive first

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

For my application i have to send data from the (python flask) server to the web client. the data the server receives is from serial or other external sources, which has to trigger the send() without a message from the client first. I am able to send a message upon a client connecting or messaging the server first, but i can't seem to initiate the send() without the client initiating the 'conversation'.

How do i do this? or is socketIO not what i need?

```
@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print('received args: ' + arg1 + arg2 + arg3)
```

Can this example code be used to initiate send from the server? If so,  how? How do i trigger a custom event from the server side?

Receiving is done from a different file than the flask file. So i need to be able to call a send function in the flask file from an external file.

All help appreciated!